# WatIn test innerText contains a whitespace at the end. HTML does not

Tags: html, watin

I'm using  WatIn to automate IE9 testing of table.
Text of cell contains a trailing whitespace that is not in the HTML.

I have stepped through the WatIn code and found it is asking for innerText attribute. The value of innerText also have the trailing whitespace

Run the same test on different machine with same IE version and testing the same web site and the whitespace is gone

How can I avoid the trailing whitespace on my machine?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen your specific issue, but I have seen slight differences of HTML output due to different versions of IE and IIS.

Trailing whitespace can be removed with the `string.TrimEnd` method.

**Example C# code**

```
string extraspaces = " spaces before and after ";
Console.WriteLine("None a" + extraspaces + "a");
Console.WriteLine("Trim a" + extraspaces.Trim() + "a");
Console.WriteLine("TrimStart a" + extraspaces.TrimStart(' ') + "a");
Console.WriteLine("TrimEnd a" + extraspaces.TrimEnd(' ') + "a");
```

Comment: I would like to keep the trailing whitespace when it is in the HTML.
If I use Trim I will in some cases remove whitespace that should have been there

Comment: The answer OCary gave is correct. And I know cause I have struggled a lot with this issue because of compatibility between IE and FF.